# Java access information from a class to another class

Tags: java, class, oop, static

I am doing my homework and I am currently trying to put note and compt in   noter() to moyenne() so I can make an average of entered notes that will be in a table of 20.

Google drive link for those who wants to check: (pdf for what to do in french):[All the informations here](http://%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B_NhaKIU5C1dY0dzSFh6amVJams?usp=sharing)

Here is noter() for grades of each

```
public static int noter() {
        int compt = 0;
        int note = 0;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            System.out.println("Veuillez entrer la note de l'etudiant: ");
            note = sc.nextInt();
            compt++;
        } while (note != -1);

        System.out.println(compt);

        return compt;
    }`
```

Here is moyenne() for average of all the grades of the students

```
    public static int moyenne() {
int etudiant[i].moyenne = 0;  

    etudiant[i].moyenne = etudiant[i].noter.note/ etudiant[i].noter.compt;
    return etudiant[i].moyenne;
}
```

Also the full code so you see the table of what I'm talking about:

```
import java.util.Scanner;  // Utiliser mode console

public class GestEtudiant {

    private static String code;
    static Etudiant[] etudiant = new Etudiant[20]; // Attributs statiques
    static int nbreEtudiants; // comment mettre pour ne depasse pas 20

        // MÃ©thodes statiques
    public static  int  ajoutEtudiant() {
        String nomTemp, prenomTemp;
        int anneeNaisTemp;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Etudiant monEtudiant = new Etudiant();

        for (int i = 0; i < etudiant.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Entrer les informations suivantes:\n1-Nom:\n2-Prenom:\n3-Annee de naissance:");

            nomTemp = sc.next();
            prenomTemp = sc.next();
            anneeNaisTemp = sc.nextInt();

            etudiant[i] = new Etudiant(nomTemp, prenomTemp, anneeNaisTemp);
            System.out.println(etudiant[i].code);

            if (i > 20) {
                System.out.println("Une erreur c'est produite, la limite d'etudiants a ete depassee, l'ajout n'a pas eu lieu ");
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }

    public static int noter() {
        int compt = 0;
        int note = 0;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            System.out.println("Veuillez entrer la note de l'etudiant: ");
            note = sc.nextInt();
            compt++;
        } while (note != -1);

        System.out.println(compt);

        return compt;
    }

    public static int moyenne() {
    int etudiant[i].moyenne = 0;  

        etudiant[i].moyenne = etudiant[i].noter.note/ etudiant[i].noter.compt;
        return etudiant[i].moyenne;
    }

    public static double meilleur() {
        // A complÃ©ter ..
        return 0;
    }

    public static double tauxEchec() {
        // A complÃ©ter ..
        return 0;
    }

        // MÃ©thode principale
    public static void main(String args []) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int option;

            //Menu rÃ©pÃ©titif
        do {
            System.out.println("Quelle opÃ©ration voulez-vous effectuer?\n(1) Inscrire un Ã©tudiant.\n(2) Entrer les notes des Ã©tudiants.\n(3) Afficher les Ã©tudiants.\n(4) Afficher les statistiques.\n(5) Quitter l'application.\n\n");
            option = sc.nextInt();

            switch(option) {

                case 1: { //Inscrire
                        // A complÃ©ter ..
                    break;
                }

                case 2: { //Noter
                    // A complÃ©ter ..
                    break;
                }

                case 3: { //Afficher
                    // A complÃ©ter ..
                    break;
                }

                case 4: { //Statistiques
                    // A complÃ©ter ..
                    break;
                }

                case 5: { //Quitter
                    // A complÃ©ter ..
                    break;
                }

                default: {
                    System.out.println("Choix Invalide - doit Ãªtre compris entre 1 et 5");
                }
            } // fin du switch
        } while (option != 5); // fin de la boucle
    } //fin main
} //fin classe
```

Comment: So where's the problem?

Comment: at moyenne I can't "transfer" the grades of noter to moyenne to make the averages of all of the 20 students Note that noter is to count all the grades of each students 1 by 1

Comment: Here is what I am trying right now:

Comment: You aren't even saving the notes entered anywhere. In your noter() method you save the last entered note in a single int and override it every time. So You will only have the last entered note in a local variable and that will get deleted by the garbage collector once the mthod is done running. You should first think about a data structure where you actually store the entered notes before you care about how you access that data from somewhere else. Because you cannot transfer/access something that doesn't exist currently.

Comment: Here is what I am trying right now: `public static int noter() {
  int compt = 0;
  int note = 0;

  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

  do {
   System.out.println("Veuillez entrer la note de l'etudiant: ");
   note = sc.nextInt();
   compt++;
  } while (note != -1);

  System.out.println(compt);
  
  int moyenne = 0; 
  moyenne= note/compt;
  
  return compt;
 }`

Comment: ` public static int moyenne() {
 int moyenne = 0;  
    for (int i = 0; i < etudiant.length; i++) {
     noteTemp = sc.nextInt();
  comptTemp = sc.nextInt();
  
  etudiant[i] = new Etudiant(noteTemp, comptTemp);
  System.out.println(etudiant[i].moyenne);
         
        etudiant[i].moyenne = noter()/comptTemp;
  return etudiant[i].moyenne;
 }`.

Comment: @911DidBush but I did compt++; to count them no?

Comment: Yes, if the count is the only thing you need then you can use the return value of the function. But the notes that got entered are gone once your noter() method is done.

Comment: @911DidBush I tried to use the class outside like noter().average so it's bad too?

Answer (score 0):

Alors, you can do this:
assign directly the average (moyenne) in method noter() like this:

```
    do {
        System.out.println("Veuillez entrer la note de l'etudiant: ");
        note += sc.nextInt(); // note here you have to add all values
        compt++;
    } while (note != -1);
    System.out.println(compt);
    etudiant[i].moyenne = note / compt;
```